# Edición de imágenes en html

Tags: jquery, html

Como puedo programar un pequeño editor de imágenes en html, de tal forma que pueda mover una imagen sobre un fondo, y en base a la posición de la ultima hacer un recorte. Existe alguna forma de hacer que la imagen de fondo tenga un contraste con la que esta enésima, esta ultima seria transparente para notar la diferencia.
Mas o menos como la siguiente imagen.

El marco rojo es como la imagen que se movería en todo el fondo y en base a eso hacer un recorte y guardar la imagen resultante

[image: El marco rojo es como la imagen que se movería en todo el fondo y en base a eso hacer un recorte y guardar la imagen resultante]

Tal vez con jQuery o algún plugin. No se mucho de html así que  no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a leer http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para evitar que tengas votaciones en contra y puedas formular preguntas con las bases definidas en el link mencionado. Por otro lado ya que mencionas "No se mucho de html", no hay problema, vamo a aprender: aquí te recomiendo estos enlaces: https://html5spain.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/12-recursos-imprescindibles-para-aprender-html5/ y un curso de la MVA de Microsoft: https://mva.microsoft.com/es-es/training-courses/jump-start-para-el-desarrollo-en-html5-con-javascript-y-css3-14446 (subtitulos en español) saludos

Answer (score 2):

Esta es la librería que necesitas:  http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

Aquí tienes un pequeño ejemplo en el `JavaScript`

```
var el = document.getElementById('vanilla-demo');
var vanilla = new Croppie(el, {
    viewport: { width: 100, height: 100 },
    boundary: { width: 300, height: 300 },
    showZoomer: false,
    enableOrientation: true
});
vanilla.bind({
    url: 'demo/demo-2.jpg',
    orientation: 4
});
//on button click
vanilla.result('canvas').then(function(base64Image) {
    // aqui es donde vamos a tener la cadena de texto en base64 de la imagen recortada
});
```

Comment: El plugin me parece bien, solo que en lugar de mover y hacer zoom al fondo, yo quiero mover el cuadro, ya este sera una imagen transparente, gracias por el aporte